# Construction of a continuous two-to-one map from the 2-sphere S^2 to the real projective plane

Tags: algebraic-topology

How can I construct a continuous two-to-one map from the 2-sphere $S^2$ to the real projective plane?

I know that a real projective plane $\Bbb RP^2$ is described to be the quotient space of $S^2$ by identifying two points. But from this, how will I be able to construct a continuous map?

Comment: It's literally the quotient map $p:S^2\to\mathbb{R}P^2$.

Comment: and what would be its elements?

Answer (score 2):

The map takes the point $p \in S^2$ to the equivalence class $\{p, -p\}$ in $\Bbb RP^2$.

Comment: ohh. okay! got it. Thanks!